QuarkusContextStorage Context in storage not the expected context
While using telemetry with quarkus, we are seeing the below message flooding our logs.
io.quarkus.opentelemetry.runtime.QuarkusContextStorage~INFO~~~[executor-thread-26]~Context in storage not the expected context, Scope.close was not called correctly. Details: OTel contex
t before: {spanId=153b3429e76952a0, traceId=4ef28ffc44a2d0ab45d3d9638e0a382f, sampled=false}. OTel context toAttach: {spanId=676849a28ef95992, traceId=4ef28ffc44a2d0ab45d3d9638e0a382f, sampled=false}

This started to happen after we recently went from quarkus 3 to 3.9, possibly due to the below:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/25102
Upgrading to 3.10 doesn't fix this issue. Anyone has a way to address this info message flooding the logs either by fixing the issue or turning off INFO messages from otel?
Thank you in advance
SG

The log level was changed to prevent flooding.
As you can see, the trace id is the same but the span ids are different. This is happening when you have 2 opened spans for the same request and they close out of order, as mentioned in the issue you linked to.
The resolution of this problem is not simple and clashes with some work planed down the road, for the support of Micrometer's Observation API.
The support of this API will touch in the same places required to fix this problem. This will be addressed then. This allows not to fix or deep refactor the same code twice.

Thank you for the response! I am trying to understand where this would occur. We don't have any custom spans in the application and all the spans are coming from either the built-in or explicitly added WithSpan annotations. not sure where they are getting closed out of order. Thanks again!
